# Slidebars Triggers Not Working (aka Slidebar)

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, navigation

This is the first time I've tried implementing this plugin. I'm excited to use it because I think it looks great. It's nice and smooth even on mobile devices, so thank you to the developer! I'm simply not able to get the toggle/trigger to work.

I have implemented Slidebars on [this site](http://development.infowest.com/passion) in development but the triggers (`.sb-open-left`, `.sb-toggle-left`, etc) are not triggering. I know the plugin is being called by the page because the code blocks with the classes `.sb-left` and `.sb-right` are hidden and adding the class `.sb-active` shows them. The site and code can be seen at [development.infowest.com/passion](http://development.infowest.com/passion)

Comment: This won't be the solution, but just noticed that the inline script where you initialize the slidebars (`$.slidebars();`) is wrapped in the tag `<script type="text/javasctipt">` (instead of `text/javascript`)

Comment: Good eye, @matthias_h and thank you! That actually did fix it! I feel embarrassed  but grateful  How do I mark your comment as the correct answer?

Comment: Glad to be of help, didn't think that could already be the fix :)  It's not possible to mark a comment as answer, so I've just added it as answer so the question can be marked as closed/solved when you mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previously mentioned as comment only - the slidebars weren't working because they were initialized wrapped in the inline script tag

```
<script type="text/javasctipt">
```

instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```